# Will bastion go back to recon mode if charged by D.va?

Tags: overwatch

I have a hard time fighting against Bastion as D.Va. My plan is to just fly through it and knock him out.

I know that Reindhardt's pin and Road Hog's grab will put Bastion into recon mode. What about D.Va? Will my plan work?

Answer (score 19):

Bastion can't be moved while in Sentry configuration by knockback effects such as D.Va's Boost or Pharah's Concussive Blast. He can only be knocked back if he is first stunned out of Sentry configuration with abilities such as Roadhog's Hook, Reinhardt's Charge, Ana's Sleep Dart, McCree's Flashbang or Sombra's Hack. Bastion can be moved by Zarya's Graviton Surge or Orisa's Halt! abilities, but will remain in Sentry Configuration while being moved.

D.Va's thrusters can't stun, only displace, so they won't work on a Sentry Bastion.

Comment: Does this mean the D.Va gets displaced when knocking into a sentry Bastion? Like, does she bounce off to one side, or can she use the Bastion to stop moving?

Comment: @KizTrap I'm fairly sure she'd just move straight through Bastion, like when boosting into a player that's right up against a wall.

Comment: Can robots be ghosts? Maybe Bastion was never re-activated in the first place.. *cue x-files music*

Comment: I haven't tested it, but my guess is it'd be the same as if she boosted into a wall.

Comment: I really wish I'd seen this answer before trying to take out a Bastion with a Zarya ult.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't move him. If you want to counter him succesfully, do not fight him alone. You should go in together with a DPS character, like soldier, mccree, jinkrat... and let him melt Bastion down, while you are holding your defense matrix up.

Comment: He can be moved, but he can't be displaced. Orisa's Halt! ability, and Zarya's Graviton Surge will both pull Bastion towards the centre in sentry mode.